# The phrase "I'm coming" has some strong sexual connotation

Tags: meaning, word-usage, connotation

Is the following statement correct?

> “I'm coming” has some strong sexual connotation

There are some guys who propose to avoid this phrase without destination.

Usecase: a comment under Facebook event with text *I'm coming!*

Comment: I think this is a useful example especially for non natives who may be unfamiliar with this issue and may find it difficult  to understand the sexual innuendo that some words may suggest.

Comment: It's only got sexual innuendo among a group of puerile boys.

Comment: We are here to help 'puerile boys' too.

Comment: What *exactly* is the question? Is the sentence grammatically correct, or what? Who are these "guys" who propose to avoid using this exclamation/invocation/statement?

Comment: It is a question on the double meaning that the expression 'I am coming' may convey.

Comment: You need to clarify *what* the question is about. It could very well be what Josh61 claims it to be, but to me, the question is unclear.

Comment: Hi guys. Actually all of you are right about the question.  I understand that the connotation depends on actual environment(age, gender etc). It's interesting to observe the discussion. Thanks

Comment: It is sense number 17 of *come* in the OED. Its earliest example is from 1650:  *Walking in Meadow Green in Bp. Percy's Loose Songs (1868)    Then off he came, & blusht for shame soe soone that he had endit.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a ***[sexual innuendo](http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Sexual_innuendo)*** as it stands. If you want to avoid any possible 'misunderstanding' you might add what you are referring to, that is *I'm coming to the event, etc.*

> - An indirect or subtle, usually derogatory implication in expression;

As noted, that innuendo would probably be used jokingly only by boys, among whom usage of sexual innuendos appears to be quite common, as suggested in the following article:

> - Originally created by authors as a way to firmly grab their readers' imaginations and caress them with an artistic touch for maximum effect, skillful use of sexual innuendo has been forced into the breadth of society.
> - Since its conception, sexual innuendo has slowly and smoothly spread across much of the face of pop culture. Despite periodic attempts by some to smear the practice, spurts of sexual innuendo continue to stick to the body of society, rivulets of which flow down into cultural nether regions and pool.
> - There are many who attempt to push sexual innuendo onto and into every-day life. ***Morals generally consider it inappropriate to thrust sexual innuendos into the minds of the youth. However, from K through 12, children constantly feel the deep impact of sexual innuendo shoved their minds by both instructors and classmates.*** This has caused a great excess of sexual innuendo to be secreted from schools.

Comment: Adding a subject is the way to go if you want to avoid any possibility of children sniggering. That may be what you meant by putting 'misunderstanding' in quotes, I'm just uncomfortable with the phrasing because it could be interpreted as saying it's something one _ought_ to do. It's not, people use the verb "to come" without an object all the time, including in the facebook usecase scenario.

Comment: I agree, I am not suggesting it should be done on a regular basis. I am just referring to the specific case.  Sexual innuendo by their subtle nature can be easily found anywhere. One should just be aware of it. The Wikipedia article is useful in that respect.

Comment: I think your answer makes it sound exactly like you are suggesting it be done on a regular basis. The difference made by the quotes around 'misunderstanding' is too subtle.

Comment: Um. You're quoting Uncyclopedia? Well then. Anyway, just a reminder that I actually shouldn't have needed to click on that link to find out the source.

Comment: @sumelic -anything better you may kindly suggest?

Comment: I posted an answer; it's not great because it's basically just my opinion. The Uncyclopedia quote tries to be funny, and I guess it might be a little bit. I don't think it really has much educational value, though.

Comment: @sumelic - well, it actually confirms what commenters have posted as of now.

Answer (score 9):

No, the phrase "I'm coming!" does not generally have a "strong sexual connotation," especially if it's given in a context such as the example you gave. It can be interpreted in a sexual manner, but so can many other normal phrases (such as "it's hard" or "it's too big"). It has been used in the title of a [children's book](https://books.google.com/books?id=Kd9qNQAACAAJ&dq=%22i'm+coming!%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD4Q6AEwCDgKahUKEwjLs7Wmq43JAhVEz2MKHRiIDP4), and also as part of written dialogues in many other books ([1](https://books.google.com/books?id=F9Oif-42vLoC&pg=PA76&dq=%22i'm+coming!%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwADgeahUKEwitq-b3q43JAhUC9GMKHe5hBHY#v=onepage&q=%22i'm%20coming!%22&f=false), [2](https://books.google.com/books?id=mmFl6xJpCzYC&pg=PA47&dq=%22i'm+coming!%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEgQ6AEwCDgeahUKEwiwm_msrI3JAhUIw2MKHX0DA7c#v=onepage&q=%22i'm%20coming!%22&f=false), [3](https://books.google.com/books?id=HS4iZMZ9o1QC&pg=PA513&dq=%22i'm+coming!%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBjgoahUKEwjT9rHTrI3JAhUN8WMKHZMbBAI#v=onepage&q=%22i'm%20coming!%22&f=false), [4](https://books.google.com/books?id=xofJ_FShYhIC&pg=PT28&dq=%22i'm+coming!%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CBsQ6AEwADgyahUKEwjAs_PqrI3JAhVYz2MKHax4Aqo#v=onepage&q=%22i'm%20coming!%22&f=false)) with no sexual meaning intended.

In fact, I found one example from Google Books where even though the term *is* used in a sexual context, the narrator explicitly is reminded of the non-sexual use of the phrase:

> Tom started moving himself quicker and quicker. 'I'm coming!' he
>   called. 'I'm coming!'  
> **He sounded like he was late picking up the
>   kids.**

([*Sugarbabe*](https://books.google.com/books?id=u2vL_WSRheAC&pg=PA192&dq=%22i'm%20coming!%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwATg8ahUKEwjqqtqArY3JAhVNwGMKHakcCOY#v=onepage&q=%22i'm%20coming!%22&f=false), by Holly Hill)

If the term inherently had a strongly sexual connotation, the sentence I bolded would not make much sense: why would someone use a sexually charged phrase when discussing picking up the kids?

If you have friends who consistently interpret things in a sexual light (maybe saying ["that's what she said"](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=that's%20what%20she%20said)) then you may add a destination to make it less prone to deliberate misinterpretation. But this is not required.